# Does Neo have the same abilities within the Construct program as he does in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

Inside the Matrix designed by the Architect, Neo has the ability to bend and break rules (including ones pertaining to death).

Does Neo have the same ability within the Construct program, which is a simulation of the Matrix written by the Zionists?

I recognize that in the first sparring program, Neo is able to convince himself that he can move faster than Morpheus. This could just be a mind over matter thing, and less of a innate ability in Neo. Who is say that others couldn't also beat Morpheus in the sparring program?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neo would have the same abilities as he does in the Matrix since The Construct was based on the Matrix program, sort of an emulation or shell program acting as a testing environment.

- The point of the Construct was to be a place where someone could learn to familiarize themselves with the nature of the Matrix as a place that was not real.
- Literally teaching people that their reality was not real and that limitations they believed placed on them were arbitrary and could be overcome.
- From what I was to understand, Morpheus was the best fighter of the group and no one could beat him in the Construct.
- Watching him being able to and willing to fight against the Matrix programs would indeed indicate he was both mentally robust enough and centered enough to hold his own even against the upgraded security programs.

Comment: In your last point, are you referring to Morpheus in the Bathroom scene where he fights Smith or to Neo?

Comment: @bitmask  maybe when he was being interrogated by Agent Smith. Also, in Reloaded, he fights an updated agent on a truck on freeway :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, though the previous answers seem to point that Neo's abilities to bend the Matrix rules were never explicitly shown in the movie, we must remember that the tatami where Morpheus fights against Neo is a sparring program built over the Construct environment.

At that fight, we watch, as Morpheus pushed Neo to the edge, that he started to bend reality, and became faster, even doing a crazy jump above Morpheus.

That sparring fight happened when Neo wasn't aware of his full capabilities, but it would be enough to state that, after improving his skills, Neo would be able use his abilities inside the Construct program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Neo should also be able to bend the Construct program in a manner similar to his bending the Matrix. Although this is never explicitly shown. The construct is a basic sandbox version of The Matrix. It follows the same coding, the same architecture, just a much smaller version, and it is essentially offline. Neo's powers work by bending the code of The Matrix. Since the construct is but a smaller offline sandbox version of The Matrix, Neo should be able to exercise his powers there as well.
This can only be avoided if the creator of The Construct deliberately includes code to counteract Neo's abilities into it.

Comment: Since it was never shown, what reason do you have for thinking this?

Comment: It is pretty straight forward. The base of the Matrix is the same between the Construct and the real thing. The construct is just a miniature bubble version of the Matrix, so all the rules of the Matrix apply there as well. We can also see that Morpheus bends gravity in the "jump" program. So if Morpheus can make this basic hack, Neo can definitely assert his Matrix powers in the construct.

Comment: Why the negative vote ?

Comment: @ash_k29 I don't know who gave it, but the only logical explanation would be that the person who gave it thought that your answer didn't give enough details or evidence to support your hypothesis.